# gradle with appengine plugin

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle

I'm trying to set a project with use of `appengine` plugin. I've multiple errors, probably because I don't know how to tie it all together.

For instance, when `gradle appengineRun` is executed, everything works fine till the moment I open the site in the browser. Then I receive:

```
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: 
Found Meta-Data for class com.sample.Message but this class is not enhanced!!
Please enhance the class before running DataNucleus.
```

Quick look at a task list shows that there is appropriate task: `appengineEnhance`. Unfortunately when the task is run it fails with an enigmatic exception J`ava returned: 1`. But in the log I found much more descriptive message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exception
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:76)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.<init>(Enhance.java:71)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.main(Enhance.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:74)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.<init>(Lorg/datanucleus/PersistenceConfiguration;Lorg/datanucleus/ClassLoaderResolver;)V
    at org.datanucleus.OMFContext.<init>(OMFContext.java:159)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.<init>(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:172)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.<init>(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:150)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1157)
    ... 7 more
```

As far as I understand there's some incompatibility between jars. Any idea how to fix that?

My `build.gradle` file is as following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.8.7'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    providedCompile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    providedCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1'

    providedCompile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'
    providedCompile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'

    def jacksonVer = '2.2.0'

    providedCompile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:$jacksonVer"
    providedCompile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$jacksonVer"

    providedCompile 'javax:javaee-api:6.0'
    providedCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.8.7'
    providedCompile 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.9-RC1'
    providedCompile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:3.1.3'

}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.10'
}

appengine {
    httpPort = 6380
}
```

Comment: Seems to me as if the Datanucleus libraries you are using are not compatible with the AppEngine SDK version. I'd try to ask about this on the AppEngine mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually after some time it turned out that it was really silly mistake. The person who was initially developing the project (at the very beginning) hasn't used any build tool and deploying straight from eclipse. In eclipse he has prepared *war* structure and all classed were copied to `WEB-INF/classes` where... `.gitignore` file was placed to ignore the content of the mentioned directory. `appengine` works fine!